# "'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named . . . "

Tags: ios, swift, types, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have created two variables that are floats:

```
var yourWeight = (yourWeightTextField.text as NSString).floatValue
var calorieNumber = (calorieNumberTextField.text as NSString).floatValue
```

I got the following errors:

```
// 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'yourWeightTextField'
// 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'yourWeightTextField'
```

I have set my IBOutlets:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var calculatorButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var inspirationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var beginningLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var calculatorContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var answer1Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var yourWeightTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var exerciseListPickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var calorieNumberTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var menuExampleButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var aboutButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!
```

Here's my ViewDidLoad Method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    yourWeightTextField.delegate = self
    calorieNumberTextField.delegate = self
    exerciseListPickerView.delegate = self
    exerciseListPickerView.dataSource = self
    calculateButton.enabled = false
    // Calling the textfield valueChanged Methods
    yourWeightTextField.addTarget(self, action:"yourWeightEditingChanged:", forControlEvents:.EditingChanged);
    calorieNumberTextField.addTarget(self, action:"calorieNumberEditingChanged:", forControlEvents:.EditingChanged);
}
```

Here's the rest of the code:

```
var yourWeight = (yourWeightTextField.text as NSString).floatValue
var calorieNumber = (calorieNumberTextField.text as NSString).floatValue
var exerciseCurrentValue:Float = 0.009
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    switch (row) {
    case (0):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.009
    case (1):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.019
    case (2):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.023
    case (3):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.029
    case (4):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.045
    case (5):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.033
    case (6):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.038
    case (7):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.038
    case (8):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.039
    case (9):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.053
    case (10):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.061
    case (11):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.063
    case (12):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.063
    case (13):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.064
    case (14):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.076
    case (15):
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.083
    default:
        exerciseCurrentValue = 0.009
    }
}

@IBAction func calculateButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    answer1Label.text = "It will take you \((exerciseCurrentValue) / ((yourWeight) * (calorieNumber))) minutes to burn off those calories by performing that exercise."
}
```

I also got another error at

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    answer1Label.text = "It will take you \((exerciseCurrentValue) / ((yourWeight) * (calorieNumber))) minutes to burn off those calories by performing that exercise."
```

, but I assume this will be fixed:

```
// 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'yourWeight'
```

Please provide as much code possible because I am new to programming. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign properties with instance values.

You need to define your properties like this.

```
var yourWeight:Float = 0 // Or whatever default value you want
var calorieNumber:Float = 0 // Or whatever default value you want
```

Then in the viewDidLoad and wherever else you need to get the values, do:

```
self.yourWeight = (self.yourWeightTextField.text as NSString).floatValue
self.calorieNumber = (self.calorieNumberTextField.text as NSString).floatValue
```